# Azure timer Function output binding record set in a queue

Tags: sql-server, azure-functions

I have a timer azure function which calls a stored proc and the proc returns a record set. What is the best way to grab a value from record set and push it in the queue using output binding on the signature of the timer function.

I need to be able to go through the contents of the table and push one column value to the queue. If there are 50 records in the record set, there will be 50 entries in the queue.

Here is my code

```
public static void FieldDevicePollingStatusDispatch_Run ([TimerTrigger("%ScheduleDispatch%")]TimerInfo myTimer,
             [Queue("%DispatchQueueName%", Connection = "AVStorageAccessKey")] out string msg, //output binding
            ILogger log)
        {
            oConnect.Open();
            DataTable oDataTable = new DataTable();
            SqlCommand objCommand = new SqlCommand("CallProc", oConnect);
            objCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            objCommand.Connection = oConnect;


            SqlDataAdapter oDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(objCommand);
            oDataAdapter.Fill(oDataTable);


            msg = // Content from the table, need one column from table.

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `return` [attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue):

```
[StorageAccount("AzureWebJobsStorage")]
public static class QueueFunctions
{
    [FunctionName("QueueOutput")]
    [return: Queue("myqueue-items")]
    public static string QueueOutput([HttpTrigger] dynamic input,  ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# function processed: {input.Text}");
        return input.Text;
    }
}
```